# Force binary number display Signed Integer?

Tags: swift

The binary representation of number 53 is `0b00110101` and -53 is `11001010`.

I used 1's complement of 53 to get the binary value of -53.

But when i try to print those binary number as

```
print(0b00110101) //53
print(0b11001010) //-53
```

I get the following output.

> 53
>
> 202

How can i make the compiler return the negative representation of the binary value?

Comment: Note that the (8-bit) 2's complement of 00110101 is 11001011, not 11001010.

Comment: (you're using 1's complement; not 2's complement)

Comment: oh yes..Thanks for the slip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0b11001010` is an *integer literal* and in `print(0b11001010)` its type is `Int` and the value is `202`.

But you can create a signed 8-bit value with the same bit pattern:

```
let x = Int8(bitPattern: 0b11001010)
// Equivalent to:
// let x = Int8(bitPattern: 202)
print(x) // -54
```

using the [Int8(bitPattern:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int8/1538918-init) initializer:

> Creates a new instance with the same memory representation as the given value.

(Here the compiler infers the type of the integer literal as `UInt8`.)

Comment: Thanks..but my head started spinning now :)