# In Swift I cant create a negative number in binary

Tags: swift, binary

I'm trying to assign -5 to signedInt but getting an error:

> Integer literal '133' overflows when stored into 'Int8'

```
let signedInt: Int8 = 0b10000101
print(signedInt)
print(String(signedInt, radix: 2))
```

[image]

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932634/force-binary-number-display-signed-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value is not `-5`, but `-123`.

You can't get there with a direct assignment because the value is a signed Int and interpreted as `133`.

To assign a negative value, use `Int8(bitpattern:)` to convert the value from a `UInt8` to an `Int8`:

```
let signedInt = Int8(bitPattern: 0b10000101)
print(signedInt)
```

> ```
> -123
> ```

---

`-5` is `0b11111011` which is the 2's complement of `0b00000101`.

To form the 2's complement, start with the binary pattern for `5`:

```
0b00000101
```

invert all of the bits:

```
0b11111010
```

and add `1`:

```
0b11111011
```

---

You can use `UInt8(bitPattern:)` to find the representation of the number:

```
let signedInt: Int8 = -5
print(String(UInt8(bitPattern: signedInt), radix: 2))
```

> ```
> 11111011
> ```